# View runtime errors in eclipse when running on physical Android device

Tags: android

I am getting a runtime error when I attempt to run my app on my physical android device, i.e a 'Force Close' dialog.

However, I am not getting a console error in eclipse IDE, is there something I must enable for me to view the error in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me...I was Running the app instead of Debugging :), still getting used to Eclipse!!

Comment: Please accept your own answer if this solved your problem so it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I thought this limit would get dropped with high enough rep.